# Changing and Centering Line Divider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a line divider the I want to be in the absolute center of page and to be dotted but this is all I found: http://jsfiddle.net/gtKBs/1133/

I have no clue how to change a straight line into a dotted line using any form of coding so I'm here.

```
.divider {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:10%;
    bottom:10%;
    border-left:1px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: Tried changing "solid" into "dotted" ?

Comment: Is the problem that your border is solid instead of dotted, that it's not centered, or both?

Comment: That it is not centered @j08691

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jZE2g/1/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dotted` [border style](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-style):

```
border-left: 1px dotted grey;
```

Refer to this **W3C wiki** page to discover more border styles: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-left-style#Values

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gtKBs/1134/

Comment: How do I get this in the center of the webpage

Comment: @user2680614 It depends on your page markup. For the provided fiddle here is the easiest way: http://jsfiddle.net/gtKBs/1135/.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
border-left:1px solid grey;
```

to:

```
border-left:1px dotted grey;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtKBs/1133/)